# Refreshing content

Tags: javascript, page-refresh

Sorry, I suck at JS but there's what I'm trying to do:

Here's the code I have. It simply calls a .php file and replaces the contents of the  which is a table.  The problem I'm having is that there's a delay between loading the content and the replacing of the contents. This causes the table I'm replacing to essentially collapse because briefly it has no contents.  The 'ajax_load' is an animated gif I tested but I really dislike that solution.

What I'd like is to have the contents loaded and then replace the table without having to show that gif and without the entire table vanishing then reappearing.  Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

```
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);

function myTimer() {
     $("#count1").html(ajax_load).load(loadUrl);
}
```

Comment: You could load it into an invisible extra element, which you then make visible and hide the show element.

Comment: Could you please give me an example of this?  I assume you mean a css visible property?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I was on the right track.

```
function myTimer() {
     $("#count1").load(loadUrl);
}
```